# Leadtools - The program failed to run with the following error: An exception occurred in the fate of the invocation

Tags: dicom, leadtools-sdk

Step 8: Configure the Storage Server Manager to use MyQueryIOD.xml
Run CSStorageServerManagerDemo.exe
Login with the Username and Password credentials that you defined during database configuration
Open the Query Settings, and set the IOD XML Path to be your MyQueryIOD.xml file. 
See Specifying C-FIND-Rsp DICOM Elements for instructions on creating MyQueryIOD.xml

[this is error occurrs when I run this CSStorageServerManagerDemo.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DCzd.png)

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.dicom~di.topics.tutorialsampledatabasefortheleadstorageserver.html

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on our website needs an update. Our support team has already reported it to the documentation department and it will be modified soon. The main correction is this:

- Open the project My.Medical.Storage.DataAccessLayer
- Open this file:
  D:\LEADTOOLS 19\Examples\DotNet\PACSFramework\CS\Tutorials\My.Medical.Storage.DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLogic\DataAccessAgent\MyStorageDbDataAccessAgent.cs
- Add the following StoreDicom() override, and recompile:

...

```
public override void StoreDicom(DicomDataSet dataSet,
   string referencedFileName,
   string token,
   string externalStoreGuid,
   string retrieveAe,
   string storeAe,
   ReferencedImages[] images,
   bool updateExistentPatient,
   bool updateExistentStudy,
   bool updateExistentSeries,
   bool updateExistentInstances)
{
   StoreDicom(dataSet, referencedFileName, retrieveAe, images, updateExistentPatient, updateExistentStudy,
              updateExistentSeries, updateExistentInstances);
}
```

If you still face problems after making this change, please send full details about what you tried and whatever errors you're getting to support@leadtools.com.